# DynamoDB low consumed write capacity with GSI

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am backfilling DynamoDB table using import feature available for table. My table has a GSI. I am setting the Write capacity units to 8K for both GSI and table.

But when i am running data pipeline to backfill the data from s3. My consumed capacity units reaches at max 4k for both GSI AND table. But when i tried the same with no GSI my consumer capacity reaches to ~8K.

Datapipeline configuration.

```
{
  "objects": [
    {
      "failureAndRerunMode": "CASCADE",
      "resourceRole": "DataPipelineDefaultResourceRole",
      "role": "DataPipelineDefaultRole",
      "pipelineLogUri": "s3://logger/logs/",
      "scheduleType": "ONDEMAND",
      "name": "Default",
      "id": "Default"
    },
    {
      "output": {
        "ref": "DDBDestinationTable"
      },
      "input": {
        "ref": "S3InputDataNode"
      },
      "maximumRetries": "2",
      "name": "TableLoadActivity",
      "step": "s3://dynamodb-emr-#{myDDBRegion}/emr-ddb-storage-handler/2.1.0/emr-ddb-2.1.0.jar,org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.tools.DynamoDbImport,#{input.directoryPath},#{output.tableName},#{output.writeThroughputPercent}",
      "runsOn": {
        "ref": "EmrClusterForLoad"
      },
      "id": "TableLoadActivity",
      "type": "EmrActivity",
      "resizeClusterBeforeRunning": "false"
    },
    {
      "writeThroughputPercent": "#{myDDBWriteThroughputRatio}",
      "name": "DDBDestinationTable",
      "id": "DDBDestinationTable",
      "type": "DynamoDBDataNode",
      "tableName": "#{myDDBTableName}"
    },
    {
      "taskInstanceType": "m3.xlarge",
      "bootstrapAction": "s3://#{myDDBRegion}.elasticmapreduce/bootstrap-actions/configure-hadoop, --mapred-key-value,mapreduce.map.speculative=false",
      "taskInstanceCount": "5",
      "name": "EmrClusterForLoad",
      "coreInstanceCount": "1",
      "coreInstanceType": "m3.xlarge",
      "amiVersion": "3.8.0",
      "id": "EmrClusterForLoad",
      "masterInstanceType": "m3.xlarge",
      "region": "#{myDDBRegion}",
      "type": "EmrCluster"
    },
    {
      "directoryPath": "#{myInputS3Loc}",
      "name": "S3InputDataNode",
      "id": "S3InputDataNode",
      "type": "S3DataNode"
    }
  ],
  "parameters": [
    {
      "description": "Input S3 folder",
      "id": "myInputS3Loc",
      "type": "AWS::S3::ObjectKey"
    },
    {
      "description": "Target DynamoDB table name",
      "id": "myDDBTableName",
      "type": "String"
    },
    {
      "default": "0.25",
      "watermark": "Enter value between 0.1-1.0",
      "description": "DynamoDB write throughput ratio",
      "id": "myDDBWriteThroughputRatio",
      "type": "Double"
    },
    {
      "default": "us-east-1",
      "watermark": "us-east-1",
      "description": "Region of the DynamoDB table",
      "id": "myDDBRegion",
      "type": "String"
    }
  ],
  "values": {
    "myDDBRegion": "us-west-2",
    "myDDBTableName": "KNEX_NODE",
    "myDDBWriteThroughputRatio": "1",
    "myInputS3Loc": "s3://DataToLoad/sampleData/"
  }
}
```

Any Suggestions to achieve maximum write throughput for write with a GSI?

Answer (score 0):

one of the main reasons can be your distribution of your hash keys in the GSI.
probably your main table has only 1 partition (this why you see it writing in 8k), and you GSI has 2 partitions (8/2 = 4k).

what is your GSI index values? maybe you should consider to change something in your hash key format in order to get good distribution. (or when your table will grow your GSI index split again).

Comment: I think max throughput per partition for dynamo is 3k. And it partitions the table if we required more throughput than that or when size grows more than 10GB. But i am only getting max throughput 4k for both table and gsi. But when i backfilled without gsi i am getting 8k for table. And hashkeys as social ids they are uniformely distributed. For GSI i am using lastUpdated date.

Comment: 1) nobody knows the max throughput per partition. (except amazon engeneers) and they dont want to tell. i think its 1k from some experiments i had done. 2) lastUpdated date is not a good distribution if your records are ordered by this. think about that your first 1M records is on the same last update date. in this case dynamodb has very bad distribution and it will split partitions while updating the db. in this case you should dis-order the records before updating the db.

Comment: I have been wrong about re-partitioning its 1K per partition for write and 3k for read.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html
I am shuffling the records before backfilling.

Comment: Hi, did you test shuffling the records? did the throughput change? i'm trying more or less the same thing with a 12M record table with a GSI and 10K wps throughput for buth and i'm just getting 4.5K wps in both table and the GSI. The interesting thing is that in the DataPipeline throughput rate i put 0.9, and i'm getting 0.45 instead which is 0.9 / 2 . Maybe the DataPipeline job is somehow detecting there is table + gsi and divides the throughput by 2 incorrectly.